# Adding Terms of Use to Bing Map

Tags: c#, asp.net, bing-maps

We've started utilizing the Bing Maps for pins, however we need to as the terms of use to the page. I'm having an issue with actually adding the terms of use to the div that contains our map. Right now I'm trying to add in a simple hyperlink element that I'll be able to play with format wise once it's actually added. The code I have is as follows:

```
//Create Hyperlink element and assign the values.
HyperLink hlTerms = new HyperLink();
hlTerms.NavigateUrl = "http://www.microsoft.com/maps/product/terms.html";
hlTerms.Text = "Terms of Use";

//Find the control, since we're testing have a safety catch to make sure it actually exists.
Control dvMap = FindControl("mapCell");
if (dvMap != null)
{
    //Add to the div.
    dvMap.Controls.Add(hlTerms);
}
```

Yet despite the attempt to use FindControl on a div that already exists with the `runat="server"`, or should by the point we get to OnPreRender, I'm getting null. What would be the best solution to actually get this working properly?

Edit: I'm not sure if people don't actually read the ToU or not, but due to having an enterprise licensing, we're required to to have the terms of use.

> **8.4 Bing Maps TOU.** You must provide a hypertext link to the Bing Maps TOU: (i) at the bottom of each page in your Company Application where the Services can be viewed or accessed, or (ii) within the terms of use of your Company Application. Microsoft may change the Bing Maps TOU from time to time. Company is responsible for notifying its end users of changes as appropriate and will comply with Microsoft’s reasonable instructions in doing so. You may not encourage or require any end user to breach the terms of the Bing Maps TOU.

Comment: Why do you need to add the link to the terms of use on your map page? The terms of use is meant for you the developer, not the end user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not required to provide a link to the terms of use for Bing Maps in your application. The terms of use are for the developer of the app to follow and not for the end user of an app.

Comment: Incorrect, in the Terms of Use, section 8.4 of the Terms of Use: "Bing Maps TOU. You must provide a hypertext link to the Bing Maps TOU: (i) at the bottom of each page in your Company Application where the Services can be viewed or accessed, or (ii) within the terms of use of your Company Application. Microsoft may change the Bing Maps TOU from time to time. Company is responsible for notifying its end users of changes as appropriate and will comply with Microsoft’s reasonable instructions in doing so. You may not encourage or require any end user to breach the terms of the Bing Maps TOU."

Comment: I'm on the Bing Maps Customer Advisory team and am the primary person who checks that customer applications are inline with our terms of use. No one puts a link to the terms of use on their webpage. If you really want to include a link, then put it in the terms of use for your site. Putting the link on your main pages is not needed. I believe this terms in the terms of use was added a long time ago when things were a lot different. I'll see about having it removed or updated the next time the terms are updated.

Comment: Thank you @rbrundritt, my supervisor and I were confused regarding this, but this is saving us a good amount of work.